# Micro SD card is not recognized when insider preview 10581 was installed

Tags: insider-preview, micro-sd

My Lumia 640XL does not show the Micro SD card in the phone. However, the apps installed in the card are visible in Translucent tiles. On clicking the app, it shows that "something is wrong with Micro SD card. I inserted the card in laptop and it is working fine there. Please let me know if it is a bug of storage sense.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The micro-SD card issues were mentioned in [the blog post](http://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2015/10/29/announcing-windows-10-mobile-insider-preview-build-10581/).

> •After moving some apps to a SD card, those apps might crash. The workaround is to reboot your phone and those apps should work fine thereafter.

There's also a thread for this issue [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_files/10581-storage-settings-and-sd-card-info/8e89b6c4-31cd-4e13-98dc-b0d20ec483e2?tm=1446136183066&auth=1).

If all else fails, you can try formatting it. But be sure to back up any important files first.

Comment: I tried everything, rebooting phone, re-inserting card, etc but still the same problem

Comment: Then I would try formatting it.

Comment: Haha.. well thanks for the support but i will try to find a different solution.